# How to remove red marks when overriding jsp in Liferay developer studio

Tags: java, liferay

I am making a hook by overriding jsp. I made an entry in the liferay-hook.xml as

```
<hook>
    <custom-jsp-dir>/META-INF/custom_jsps</custom-jsp-dir>
</hook>
```

inside custom_jsps, i made a /html/portlet/login.jsp page and copied the content from /tomcat/webapps/root/html/portlet/login.jsp to it.It is full of red marks. I want to ask how to remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this FAQ from Liferay documatation: https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE+Developing+Liferay+Hooks#section-Liferay+IDE+Developing+Liferay+Hooks-Custom+JSPs+have+lots+of+errors+markings,+how+do+I+remove+them?